# Python: Parallelizing a nested for loop

Tags: python

I'm a little lost in trying to use the `multiprocessing` module. I have a simple nested loop to do some copying of attributes from one object to another:

```
        if objects:
            rb_from = obj_act.rigid_body
            # copy settings
            for o in objects:
                rb_to = o.rigid_body
                if o == obj_act:
                    continue
                for attr in self._attrs:
                    setattr(rb_to, attr, getattr(rb_from, attr))
```

If nothing else, I'd like to parallelize the inner loop, but it's not clear to me how to do that. Most of the examples here focus on using the `map` function of `multiprocessing`, but I don't really care about the return value from `setattr`, I just want those calls to execute in parallel.

Comment: You can parallelize function call, but not for loops. You will have to reorganize your code a bit. Also your payload seems to be rather small, with the overhead of spawning processes it might even get slower.

Comment: And additionally all processes have their own variables. Setting an attribute will not be reflected in the main process.

Comment: This is a terrible use of multithreading.  All of your threads depend on a single object.  You are best off parallelizing the outer loop, and I don't think you're going to gain very much there, either.

Answer (score 1):

You may not achieve what you want using `multiprocessing`. (Or, it could be rather complex.) Variables out of the context are not shared among processes. But they are among threads.

You can simply use `threading` and parallelize copying executions.

```
    def copy_attributes(self, obj_act, o): 
        rb_from = obj_act.rigid_body

        rb_to = o.rigid_body
        if o == obj_act:
            return
        for attr in self._attrs:
            setattr(rb_to, attr, getattr(rb_from, attr))

    ...

            for o in objects:
                threading.Thread(
                    target=self.copy_attributes, args=(obj_act, o)
                ).start()
```